# How does the control flow work in async-await?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to understand the control flow of asynchronous code in C#.

I understand the concept that when an async method comes across an "await", that it gives control back to the method that called it, allowing the thread to continue doing work instead of being blocked.

What I don't understand is when does the thread go back to the method that contained the "await" and finish the method? Is the flow decided at compile time, or is it done at runtime where the thread's flow is dictated by whichever awaited method has finished first?

When I've tried to look into the answer all I see is "it's something to do with a state machine, it depends on the compiler, and its too complicated to explain".

I've got two example pieces of code that I'd like to know the flow of and know what order the logs will be in.

```
  public async Task<ActionResult> Main()
  {

      var task1 = SomeMethod("1");
      var task2 = SomeMethod("2");
      var task3 = SomeMethod("3");
      var task4 = SomeMethod("4");

      await task2;
      await task3;
      await task4;
      await task1;

      return Ok();
  }

  private async Task SomeMethod(string input)
  {
      await Task.Delay(rnd.Next(1, 200));
      Console.WriteLine(input);
  }
```

```
    private async Task Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1");
        var result = Method1();
        Console.WriteLine("2");
        await result;
        Console.WriteLine("3");
    }

    private async Task Method1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("4");
        var result = Method2();
        Console.WriteLine("5");
        await result;
    }

    private async Task Method2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("6");
        var result = Method3();
        Console.WriteLine("7");
        await Task.Delay(300);
        await result;
    }

    private async Task Method3()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("8");
        await Task.Delay(300);
        Console.WriteLine("9");
    }
```

Comment: Have you read through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/?

Comment: You wanna know order of logs among method calls with random.Next inside?)

Comment: I would suggest to reduce the examples to one. Having to explain step-by-step the flow of two programs in a single answer is too much IMHO.

Comment: @gunr2171 I have read it yeah, the closest I see it it explaining my question is this section https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/#start-tasks-concurrently but it doesn't tell me for example when the control flow will go back to the FryBaconAsync method

Comment: @Ryan what I was trying to get at with that example was asking does the order of awaiting the methods affect their execution. So the four calls to SomeMethod() are non blocking as they're not awaited, which means that the thread goes into each of them logs the message and the passes the control back to the calling thread. I'm trying to figure out when control goes back so the SomeMethod() calls and if the first "await task2" affects the control flow.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I was hoping they'd be easy enough to someone that understands this to figure out the order quickly, is that not the case?

Answer (score 0):

> What I don't understand is when does the thread go back to the method that contained the "await" and finish the method?

It doesn't, actually. `async` methods are not tied to threads. I have in my [`async` and `await` blog post](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) a description of how they work that tries to avoid going into the weeds with state machine details, but also gives you everything you need to know. Specifically:

- `await` will capture a context by default. This "context" is usually `SynchronizationContext.Current`; in Console applications, there usually isn't  a `SynchronizationContext`, so the thread pool context is used.
- When an `async` method resumes after an `await`, it will resume on that context. In the case of the thread pool context, the continuation is just scheduled onto the thread pool.

Now, there are other situations (notably, UI applications) where there is a `SynchronizationContext` and that `SynchronizationContext` *is* tied to a specific thread (the UI thread). But that's not the case here.

Your first code example runs 4 asynchronous methods concurrently. Each of them will continue on a thread pool thread and write its output from there. The result is a random order, but all 4 will always be written.

Your second code example will result in:

```
1
4
6
8
7
5
2
{after 300ms}:
9
3
```

Breaking it down (again, flow is described in my [`async` intro](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) post):

- `Main` prints `1` and invokes `Method1`.
- `Method1` prints `4` and invokes `Method2`.
- `Method2` prints `6` and invokes `Method3`.
- `Method3` prints `8` and invokes `Task.Delay`. `Task.Delay` returns a task that will complete after 300ms.
- `Method3` `await`s the task returned from `Task.Delay`. This causes `Method3` to return an incomplete task to `Method2`.
- `Method2` prints `7` and invokes `Task.Delay`. `Task.Delay` returns a task that will complete after 300ms.
- `Method2` `await`s the task returned from `Task.Delay`. This causes `Method2` to return an incomplete task to `Method1`.
- `Method1` prints `5` and `await`s the task returned from `Method2`. This causes `Method1` to return an incomplete task to `Main`.
- `Main` prints `2` and `await`s the task returned from `Method1`.

After ~300ms, both of the `Task.Delay` tasks complete, and the continuations for `Method3` and `Method2` are scheduled to the thread pool. There is a race condition here, but it doesn't have any observable result on the output. If `Method2` executes first, it will just `await` the task returned from `Method3` anyway. So:

- `Method3` resumes executing (on a thread pool thread).
- `Method3` prints `9` and completes.
- `Method2` resumes executing (on a thread pool thread).
- `Method2` completes.
- `Method1` resumes executing (on a thread pool thread).
- `Method1` completes.
- `Main` resumes executing (on a thread pool thread).
- `Main` prints `3` and completes.